# loading image into temporay DC in MFC/C++

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I load a image into a tempory Dc and try to get  back the color when i click on my ACTIVEX controlwith container is C#.

```
CString myfunction(HWND hWnd,CDC* dc,CPoint point)
{   
    CString str;
    CBitmap bmpCOM;
    BITMAP bm;  
    bmpCOM.LoadBitmap(IDB_ROKU);
    bmpCOM.GetBitmap(&bm);
    CDC dcMem;
    dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
    dcMem.SelectObject(bmpCOM);
    HDC hdcMem=dcMem;
    COLORREF clr= GetPixel(hdcMem,point.x,point.y);
    str.Format("W:%d H:%d {X:%d Y=%d}RGB(%d,%d,%d)",bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,point.x,point.y,GetRValue(clr),GetGValue(clr),GetBValue(clr));
    return str;
}
```

the issue is at the point{x=10,y=10} is value i need but the temp dc  only return the value i need at point {x=12,y=15}.
Please help me.

Comment: What coordinate system is your incoming `CPoint` in? Client? Screen? You may also need to adjust for top-down vs. bottom-up bitmaps.

Comment: i used CPOINT from LBUTTONDOWN. How to adjust  please?

Comment: You can ping @RogerRowland otherwise he may not see your followup question. You are using client coordinates. But maybe your bitmap is drawn on the canvas starting at (2,5) instead of starting at (0,0)